# Compare two Color objects

Tags: c#, .net, colors, system.drawing

This is VS2010 and .NET 4.0. I'm trying to compare two `System.Drawing.Color` objects.

The value of `mStartColor.ToArgb()` is `16777215`.

The value of `Color.Transparent.ToArgb()` is `16777215`.

The value of `mStartColor <> Color.Transparent` is `True`.

How is equality implemented for `Color` objects?

### EDIT

Thanks everyone. I got my answer, though it doesn't make much sense to me (see my comments to Tim's and Dave's answers below). I'll mark Tim's post as the answer and he was the first to reply, but Dave's answer is equally informative.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Always read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first:

> "To compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should use
>   the ToArgb method. This is because the Equals and Equality members
>   determine equivalency using more than just the ARGB value of the
>   colors. For example, Black and FromArgb(0,0,0) are not considered
>   equal, since Black is a named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is not"

Comment: Thanks. It does help (in fact a precise answer), but doesn't make much sense to me. If they are equivalent for all practical purposes, why would their objects not be equal?

Comment: @dotNET: because they are not the same colors in a strict manner. I don't know where `Color.Equals` or Color-`==` is used everywhere. So even if a color look like another it's not the same if it hasn't for example  the same name or the same `KnownColor`.

Answer (score 18):

Colour structs have more data contained in them, than just the actual colour information, such as

```
Color [Transparent] 
R: 255 
G: 255 
B: 255 
A: 0 
IsKnownColor: True 
IsEmpty: False 
IsNamedColor: True 
IsSystemColor: False 
Name: Transparent
```

Color.FromArgb(16777215)

```
Color [A=0, R=255, G=255, B=255] 
R: 255 
G: 255 
B: 255 
A: 0 
IsKnownColor: False 
IsEmpty: False 
IsNamedColor: False 
IsSystemColor: False 
Name: ffffff
```

Equals comparisons will use all of these to determine equality. you should be diong what you already suggested, and use:

```
Color.Transparent.ToArgb().Equals(mStartColor.ToArgb())
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Roughly the same as Tim's answer below. What I don't like is that all the other fields you have listed are read-only, and presumably compute their values directly based on the values of A, R, G and B. So why wouldn't Equals() work the way we expect it to?

Comment: I would assume that all of the "System" colours are pre-defined as constants

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method which would compare the ARGB value of two colour objects and return true if they are the same.

Here is the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) on extension methods.