# C# Detect Color change of center screen pixel

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to detect the color change of the center screen pixel. But somehow it would always return the first change.

My current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pixelChange
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Color startingColor;

        // Get center pixel color rbg once the form loaded
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startingColor = GetPixelColor(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);
        }

        // Timer which calls the GetPixelColor to check for a difference
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkForColorDifference(startingColor);
        }

        // Get pixel color function
        public Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
        {
            Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics gph = Graphics.FromImage(snapshot))
            {
                gph.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }

            return snapshot.GetPixel(x, y);
        }

        // Function to check if the color of the center pxiel changed
        public void checkForColorDifference(Color start)
        {
            Color starting = start;
            Color currentColor = GetPixelColor(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);

            if (starting != currentColor)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Color: " + start + " changed to:" + currentColor.ToString() + ".", "Color change response");
                startingColor = currentColor;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How the code works so far:

1. Form1_Load get's triggered and the public Color startingColor; gets filled with a color which is the result from the GetPixelColor function.
2. A timer calls the checkForColorDifference function on each tick.
3. checkForColorDifference function accepts the startingColor as a parameter and grabs another color to compare the colors in the following way: starting.ToString() != currentColor.ToString()
4. If the colors wouldn't match, a messagebox would show and the public Color startingColor; should get filled with the second color which is stored inside  Color currentColor.

But the code would always return the same wrong response (The first response). What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of the problem: [https://i.gyazo.com/0162e404a3ecef2820024e4f93678d2a.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg4fg.png)

Comment: @d45ndx, you should be comparing the colors directly, not comparing the string representations.  Can you tell us what values `starting` and `currentColor` have?  Those are both of type `System.Drawing.Color`, which have lots of properties.  Tell us about those values so that we can know why it's not working how you want.

Comment: Edited the if part and the problem is startingColor is not getting updated. So it compares always the same colors. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg4fg.png

Comment: The color doesn't get updated until you close the message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the timer until you acknowledge the message box that is displayed.  The code will 'stop' at the MessageBox.Show() line until you click OK.  so the new color doesn't get set until after you click OK.  Meanwhile the timer is still running because of rather arcane winforms logic.

```
    public void checkForColorDifference(Color start)
    {
        Color starting = start;
        Color currentColor = GetPixelColor(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);

        if (starting != currentColor)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Color: " + start + " changed to:" + currentColor.ToString() + ".", "Color change response");
            startingColor = currentColor;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Bonus fix, using for disposable bitmap:

```
    public Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
    {
        using (Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        using (Graphics gph = Graphics.FromImage(snapshot))
        {
            gph.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            return snapshot.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to compare colors using ToString()... Show [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994753/compare-two-color-objects)  answer to know how to do it right way:

You have to compare argb values.

Comment: Already fixed this part, thanks for bringing this up to my attention, the current problem is the following: startingColor is not getting updated. So it compares always the same colors. Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/Rg4fg.png