# Maintaining a live list of game objects based on their color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two white sprite gameobjects. One has been colored red and the other green using the color picker in the Sprite Renderer. The RGB values are the same as the ones in the code below. Both have the tag 'object'.

I have 3 lists that I need to keep updated during gameplay - totalObjects, redObjects & greenObjects, containing their respective gameobjects. I am able to populate totalObjects, but not the other two.

Here's the code-

```
public List<GameObject> totalObjects = new List <GameObject>();         
public List<GameObject> redObjects = new List <GameObject>();
public List<GameObject> greenObjects = new List <GameObject>();

private Color red = new Color (0.9f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f); 
private Color green = new Color (0.8f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 1.0f); 

void Awake()
    {
        totalObjects.AddRange (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("object"));

        foreach (GameObject x in totalObjects)
        {
            if (x.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == red)
            {   
                redObjects.Add(x);
            }
            else if (x.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == green)
            {
                greenObjects.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }

void Update () 
    {
        totalObjects.RemoveAll(GameObject => GameObject == null);
        redObjects.RemoveAll(GameObject => GameObject == null);
        greenObjects.RemoveAll(GameObject => GameObject == null);
    }
```

Also, the color of the objects can change during gameplay (red > green & vice versa) if they enter a particular area, by a OnTriggerEnter2D. How do I update these changes in the lists?

Comment: Well, can't you simply update the lists from the trigger?

Comment: How should I go about doing this? For eg. If a red object changed to green, it needs to be removed from the red list and added to the green list. I guess,  in a way, the lists always need to be 'scanning' for the colors of all the objects, so it can track any changes. Also, for some reason, the nested if statements within the foreach loop do not work.

Comment: i guess the objects wont change color on their own, so when you change color, remove them from the one list and add them to the other ...

Comment: I guess i was overthinking this one. Any idea why the nested if statements are not working? I cant seem to be able to fill the color lists.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have a look to this topic: [Compare two Color objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994753/compare-two-color-objects)

> "To compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should use
>   the ToArgb method. This is because the Equals and Equality members
>   determine equivalency using more than just the ARGB value of the
>   colors. For example, Black and FromArgb(0,0,0) are not considered
>   equal, since Black is a named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is not"

2) If you have triggers on color change, why you don`t control objects in lists in a trigger handlers? It will much more effective. 
Especially if you will add some handlers on creation of object and "killing" of object.

3) Maybe you should clear your lists when you populate them again in Awake() method even if you are calling Update() methor before if?
You delete "dead' ojects in Update and add to list "living" objects again.
It seems that you will get dublicated objects in lists without that.

Comment: The colors do change on trigger. But, how do I update the lists to show this change? Like, anytime a red object is changed to green, it needs to be removed from the red list and added to the green list automatically.

Comment: You already answered your question: When trigger fires on color change from red to green for example: RedObjectList.Remove(changing_object); GreenObjectList.Add(changing_object);

Comment: Yes, I was needlessly complicating things. But, the if statements being used to fill the color lists on Awake() still don't work. Any idea why?

Comment: If you still want to use Awake method than like I said you net not to forget to clear whole lists before adding items! For example: you have only one RED object. It changed color to green. You call Awake() method, compare color of object and add it to the GreenObjectList. But it still remains in RedObjectList and you have both lists with same object! You need to remove it from RedColorLists or call Clear() to all the lists in begining of Awake() method! And again... Are you sure that == comparing works fine?

Comment: Try to simulate next situation: Create environment with one Red object. Change it color to green. Call Awake(method). Check if comparing of color object goes fine. In the end of Awake() method have a look to items in both lists. Pretty simple...

Comment: Got it working. Shifted the code from Awake() to Start() and now everything works. Not really sure how, but there it is. Color comparison seems to be working fine for now.